# Mongoose silently fails database write

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to write a simple web app with node.js, Express and MongoDB. I followed the instructions on the [Mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/), but my code seems to fail silently when I'm trying to write to the DB.

I include the following code in my main app.js -file with `var db = require("./db")`:

```
// db.js

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema
  , ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var server_name = "localhost";
var db_name = "database";

var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://'+server_name+'/'+db_name);
log.debug('Connecting to MongoDB "'+db_name+'" at '+server_name);

// Database schemas

var Compo = new Schema({
  name : String,
  description : String
});

var compoModel = mongoose.model('Compo', Compo);

var compoModelInstance = new compoModel();
compoModelInstance.name = "Competition name.";
compoModelInstance.description = "Competition description.";

compoModelInstance.save(function (err) {
  if (err !== null) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("Save successful.");
  }
});
```

The connection is created successfully, since it shows up in the mongod console output.
The program also prints out "Save successful.", but when I inspect the situation from the mongo shell with `db.database.find();` I can see the database is still empty.

Why isn't the object saved?

Comment: Your code works very well... Check that you are looking at the right place.. If you still face the same problem then explain how are you connecting to mongo shell and what commands you are issuing in mongo shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and it works fine for me. Are you looking in the right place for your data?

Connect with your mongo shell and try the following:

```
use database;
db.compos.find()
```